# What is the range of angle in front of longest triangle edge?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

What is the minimum and the maximum values of the angle $\gamma$ in front of the longest triangle edge?

[image]

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think, that max is 180, min is 60. But I'm not sure.

Comment: Why are you not sure? Min is correct (as mathlove suggests below). About max, it depends: if you have an angle of 180 degrees, it is up to you whether you consider the result a triangle, some people would not. In that case, there is no maximal angle (though we can get arbitrarily close).

Comment: Thanks, tomasz, but it was not obvious for me. How about $\alpha$, $\beta$ ranges? Are their ranges also so obvious?

Comment: They have ranges of $(0,60^\circ], (0,90^\circ)$, respectively. I'm sure you can show that -- it's more or less the same arguments.

Comment: @tomasz Ok, you are right again. I am not as good in Math as you are. I just wanted an explanation. Thanks for you attention and time.

Comment: You're welcome. That's the purpose of this site, to ask questions and learn. You don't get to be good without learning. Feel free to ask if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the minimum :

Let $\alpha\le \beta\le \gamma$ be the inner angles of a triangle.

Suppose that $\gamma\lt 60^\circ$. Then,
$$180^\circ=\alpha+\beta+\gamma\lt 60^\circ+60^\circ+60^\circ=180^\circ,$$
which is a contradiction.

Hence, we have $\gamma\ge 60^\circ$. The equality is attained when a triangle is an equilateral triangle.

Comment: Thank you, mathlove, for your clear answer, which leaves no considerations that 60 is the minimum angle.