# What are the ranges of triangle angles?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Lets say, that $\alpha \le \beta \le \gamma$. As shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950967/what-is-the-range-of-angle-in-front-of-longest-triangle-edge), $60 \le \gamma \lt 180$. What are the minimum and maximum values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

[image]

**The answer**:
$$0\lt \alpha \le 60 \\ 0 \lt \beta \lt 90\\ 60 \le \gamma \lt 180$$

Comment: Do you know that $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=180^\circ$?

Comment: Ok, you are right, that implies, that $0 \le \alpha \le 60$ and $0 \le \beta \le 60$. Am I right?

Comment: Can you obtain a triangle if $\alpha = 0$?

Comment: Lets say, that a line is degenerated triangle, then yes.

Comment: Your range for $\beta$ is wrong.

Comment: @TonyK How do you prove it?

Comment: $\beta$ can be greater than $60^{\circ}$. Think about it.

Comment: @TonyK Yes, you are right. The second guess is that the upper $\beta$ bound is 90. As shown in the case, when $\alpha \rightarrow 0$, $\beta \rightarrow 90$ and $\gamma \rightarrow 90$. Write it as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha \le \beta \le \gamma$ are triangle angles, then their ranges are:
$$
0^\circ \lt \alpha \le 60^\circ\\
0^\circ \lt \beta \lt 90^\circ\\
60^\circ \le \gamma \lt 180^\circ$$

**Proof**
The lower $\alpha$, $\beta$ and the upper $\gamma$ bounds can be determined from the case, when $\gamma \rightarrow 180^\circ$, $\alpha \rightarrow 0^\circ$, $\beta \rightarrow 0^\circ$. Since $\alpha + \beta + \gamma = 180^\circ$, $\gamma$ cannot be greater than $180^\circ$. And $\alpha$, $\beta$ cannot be $\le 0^\circ$, because when $\alpha = 0^\circ$ we get a line, not a triangle. Hence, $0^\circ < \alpha$, $0^\circ < \beta$ and $\gamma < 180^\circ$.

The upper $\beta$ bound can be determined from the case, when $\gamma \rightarrow 90^\circ$, $\beta \rightarrow 90^\circ$ and $\alpha \rightarrow 0^\circ$. Since $\alpha \ne 0^\circ$, $\beta \le \gamma \lt 90^\circ$. Hence, $\beta \lt 90^\circ$.

Since $\alpha \le \beta \le \gamma$, we get that the upper $\alpha$ bound is when $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = 60^\circ$. So, $\alpha \le 60^\circ$.

[MathLove proved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/950967/what-is-the-range-of-angle-in-front-of-longest-triangle-edge#answer-950982) that the lower $\gamma$ bound is $60^\circ$. The proof is:

> Let $\alpha \le \beta \le \gamma$ be the inner angles of a triangle. Suppose that $\gamma \lt 60^\circ$. Then, $180^\circ = \alpha + \beta + \gamma \lt 60^\circ + 60^\circ + 60^\circ = 180^\circ$ which is a
>   contradiction.

Hence, $60^\circ \le \gamma$. $\Box$

Answer (score 0):

The minimum values of $\alpha $ and $\beta $

Suppose that AB line tends to infinity angle $\gamma $ tends to $180^0$ and the other two angles tends to $0$ but they will not be zero.

Therefore $\alpha ,\ beta $ are greater than zero and can be very close to zero but not equal to zero otherwise the figure would not be a triangle.

The maximum value of  $\alpha ,\ beta $

Since $\gamma $ cannot be less than $60^0$ sum of angles in a triangle is $180^0$

Consider $\gamma $ to be $90^0$

$\alpha+\beta \le 180^0-90^0$

Now since $\alpha \le \beta \le \gamma $ the maximum values of $\alpha $ and $\beta $ are very close to $90^0$

Comment: I think, that you are wrong. $\gamma \ge 60$ does not imply, that $\beta \le 60$. Consider the case, when $\alpha \rightarrow 0$ and $\beta \rightarrow 90$, $\gamma \rightarrow 90$. I guess that the $\beta$ upper bound is $90$.

Comment: @niekas, yes, that seems right.

Comment: I am considering $\gamma $ to be minimum that is $60^0$ so that sum of other two angles $\le $ $120^0$ and according to the given condition $\alpha $ and $\beta $ cannot be less than $\beta $ so it follows... @niekas

Comment: In this particular case, when $\gamma = 60$ we have that $\alpha = 60$ and $\beta = 60$. But when $\gamma \gt 60$ it implies that $\beta$ can be higher than $60$ ($\beta \le \gamma$). And in my given case $\beta \le \gamma \lt 90$.

Comment: Oh Thankyou for the description editing the answer right now..@niekas

Comment: And still this answer is not exact. $\alpha$ upper bound is $60$, not $90$.

Comment: I don't think so because if $\beta $ tends to zero and gamma is 90 then alpha tends to $ 90^0$